# Vb.net calling images via Resource or HDD/SSD

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, embedded-resource

I was wondering what was less-taxing on the CPU... To call an PNG image from a resource or calling it from a director (c:\blah\here.png)?

Resource:

```
PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.APNGPic
```

Via Directory:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\blah\APNGPic.png")
```

I will have a lot of images on the form and some (about half) will change when a user clicks on it.

Comment: Read from Memory is faster than read from SATA disk.

Comment: There comes a point where adding images to you exe can make the exe large.  When you start an EXE, it has to be read into memory and if it is 300MB, this will take a few seconds before the user gets any indication of anything happening. I usually prefer the faster loading EXE, and then only load the images I need, when I need them over the option to load everything at once.

Comment: @ElektroStudios even if its a SSD?

Comment: @StealthRT Yes, an SSD is a memory device but it is for storage. RAM can read around 12.800 MB/s or higher (if you have 3 RAM cards then multiply = 38,400 MB/S), every year RAM max vlaues are increased with newer technologies so I don't know exactly which is the max reading speed right now, but an SSD will be around 250 MB/s.

Comment: @ElektroStudios i bet you meant 12,800 and not 12.800, right?

Comment: You can google it to check actual values, this is from 2011: Fastest SSD (OCZ Z) = 1400 MBps
DDR3-2500 = 20,000 MBps

Comment: @ElektroStudios place that as you answer and ill give you credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read from Memory is faster than read from disk.

An SSD is a memory device but it is for storage. RAM is volatile but can read around 20000 MB/s or higher, every year the computing technologies advance increasing this values so sorry I don't know exactly the max speed for actual RAM's, but an SSD will be around 250-500 MB/s.

You can google it to check actual values,

This is from 2011: `Fastest SSD (OCZ Z) = 1400 MBps DDR3-2500 = 20,000 MBps`